# C# Winform app with google Drive API. Way to automate login?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm creating a desktop application in C# that will act as a backup program. What I want to do is allow a user to create a schedule for when a backup should happen. I created a windows service that runs in the background that will run based on this schedule.

Right now, my program will copy files that the user has selected to another local user-selected folder. However, I want to extend this to allow users to backup their files to the cloud on a scheduled basis, specifically, their Google Drive account.

I'm not sure if this is possible, though, or how to go about it. I've got code working that will upload files to a Drive account, however, that requires the user to grant permission to my program each and every time it runs. My question is, how can I accomplish this to be done automatically? Is there a way to have a user enter his login credentials once and then allow the program to access their Drive account automatically thereafter, without them having to grant permission every time?

Comment: If you are using OAuth 2.0 you need to supply the code in question.  "Is there a way to have a user enter his login credentials once and then allow the program to access their Drive account automatically thereafter, without them having to grant permission every time?" - Sure...Use OAuth 2.0

Comment: can you share the code working that will upload files to a Drive account i was looking for that and got to this question of yours .

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the access token for your user somewhere and use it to request a new short term access token when you do the backup. From the Google Drive API Docs:

> Google Drive applications only receive a long-lived refresh token
>   during the very first exchange of an authorization code. This refresh
>   token is used to request new access tokens after a short-lived access
>   token expires, and it must be stored in the application's database to
>   be retrieved every time the user returns to the app.

[See the documentation here for setting up OAuth in your application](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet#setting_up_the_client_id_client_secret_and_other_oauth_20_parameters)