# How to automate a google drive desktop login using C#

Tags: c#, automation, google-drive-api, background-process, user-experience

I have an application that is used for `logging` the employees to the **vmware desktop**. Our company uses **Google mail** for email with our company domain name.

> Now , what I want to do is grab the username and password from that
>   application (which was written in C#) and use it to login to google
>   drive without interfering the user experience.

So far, I tried using 
`Process()` class to open google drive and `SendKeys()` method to fill the email and password form for them. However, I have not been able to do this whole process in a background.

> **Is there any way to open google drive and run it in background and fill the form?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want information related to `background process` See here

> [Develop a program that runs in the background in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027051/how-to-develop-a-program-that-runs-in-the-background-in-net)

If you want to see `Google Drive API` information See here

> [C# Winform app with google Drive API. Way to automate login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043884/c-sharp-winform-app-with-google-drive-api-way-to-automate-login)